# File not being created in the specific directory

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, filepath

I would like to create a user json file and add the username to it. Everything works, but the only issue is that it keeps creating the json file in the parent directory of the source file, and not in the specific "file_location" path.

```
import json

user_name = input("Username: ")

#user_names is the directory I would like the file to be created in
file_location = "desktop/python_work/files_c10/user_names/"+user_name+".json"

print(f"{file_location}")

def add_user(file_location):
    with open(file_location,'w') as f:
         json.dump(user_name,f)


 add_user(user_name)
```

Comment: Put `print(f"{file_location}")` in the `add_user` function and see what you get.

Answer (score 2):

`add_user(file_location)` insted of  `add_user(user_name)` ?

Comment: This worked thank you. I didn't realize the function parameter is being passed as the name and not the file path during my call.